# Where con el auth de Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

en estoy haciendo publica una variable que compara el id de una tabla con el `auth id` del usuario que a iniciado sesión. Siempre he hecho esto para sacar el id de usuario logueado, pero no se si al estar haciendo algo publico no me deja.

```
public $notificaciones;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->notificaciones = Aviso::where('admin_id', auth()->user()->id)->where('fecha', $ldate = date('yy-m-d'))->where('estado', 0)->count(); 
        
    }
```

Me devuelve esto:

> Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Comment: ¿Esta consulta dónde la estás intentado hacer?

Comment: En mi controlador general de la aplicación, antes de las funciones antes de mis funciones pricipales, queria hacerla publica @BetaM

Comment: Ok, entiendo que en el controlador donde tienes programada el resto de la lógica, pero me causa curiosidad ¿por qué en el constructor de la clase?

Comment: Mmmm es la unica forma que conozco de hacer una variable publica

Comment: Igual y no estoy comprendiendo del todo lo que intentas hacer, pero ¿por qué pública?, es decir ¿qué diferencia tienes entre declararla dentro de un método cualquiera o asignarle un valor en cuanto la declaras?. Igual si explicas mas a detalle lo que intentas hacer luego con este resultado comprendemos mejor

Comment: Te comento es para poner un globo con el numero de notificaciones, y quiero que este en todas la paginas, es la unica forma que se me ocurrio